# How to properly call Single/Maybe in RxJava2, do I need subscribeOn and observeOn and flatMap?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, observable

Does it make sense to use `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` and `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` for RxJava2 Single and Maybe? It doesn't seem like it makes sense since Single and Maybe only emit one event?? So I have it as follows

```
Disposable disposable = getApi()
            .signOutUserMutation(new SignOutUserRequest())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<Response<ResponseBody>>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Response<ResponseBody> responseBodyResponse) throws Exception {

                }
            }, (Throwable) -> {})
```

Would I need to map the results using `flatMap` or some sort?

Answer (score 1):

Of cause you should use

`subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` and `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` 
It doesn't matter what you use : Single, Observable or Maybe.

The main reason is

- Schedulers.io() - for input/output operations
- AndroidSchedulers.mainThread() for computation work

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `subscribeOn()` and `observeOn()` in your api as you want to switch thread when making an api request.or else you are going to get `NetworkOnMainThreadException`